# Django Celery Beat does not running tasks on time

Tags: python, django, celery, celerybeat

I'm using Django celery beats for my project and there is a problem in beat intervals.
I setup a task to run every 1 minute. But the celery run this task like every 3 minutes!

**:19

**:22

**:25

what is the problem?

================= UPDATE =================

Celery config:

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
```

[image]

Also there is nothing special in Task. It's just fetching some data from an API and them send a request to another API.

The code I'm using for running celery:

```
celery -A projectname worker --beat --scheduler django --loglevel=info
```

Comment: You'll need to show us some code, at least celery beat config. Are you using some non-default scheduler like django-celery-beat?

Comment: I updated content and added codes and commands.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's hard to tell what's wrong. Try running celery and celery beat as two separate commands (with `--scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler`). Also try to delete any `.celerybeat` files in your project root if there are any